# org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: Could not return sample

Tags: jmeter, distributed, master-slave

I am running Jmeter test in distributed mode. I have set up SSH tunneling for slaves since they are not in same region.  I have executed 2700 users  which ran fine. When we try to run 5200 users, users are going into finished status although steady state is 1 hours. I am using ultimate thread group. 
4500 users are running fine and 600 Users are going into finished state out of 5200 usesr.

Seeing below error in Jmeter Server logs:

ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: Could not return sample
               at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.StandardSampleSender.sampleOccurred(StandardSampleSender.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
                java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
                at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]

Any idea? What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from logs that you tunnel is broken:

> Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1;

See this:

- https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open

Answer (score 0):

The error is about JMeter slave being unable to establish connection to deliver results to the master so the problem is on SSH server side, you can look into its logs to see what went wrong.

The options are in:

1. SSH stands for "**Secure** Shell" so all the traffic gets encrypted. It also gets compressed in order to decrease footprint. When it comes to high loads it might be the case SSH server and/or client consumes a lot of resources and i.e. being killed by [OOM Killer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) or whatever. You can try [configuring your SSH server](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd_config/) to disable compression and use weaker encryption algorithm, for example [`arcfour`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4)
2. It might be easier to move "master" to the "other region" than passing a lot of test results over SSH
3. Another option could be using [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) with no encryption, this way all JMeter nodes will be in the same subnet.
4. And finally you can disable automatic sending of test results from slaves to the master:

   - set `mode=DiskStore` property on JMeter Slaves
   - when your test is finished collect results from slaves and copy them over to master
   - use [Merge Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)  in order to combine multiple results into single .jtl file. Merge Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)